# No sound at Headphone jack in ubuntu - Audio not working

Tags: sound, alsa

i've a problem with my headphone audio output. It doesn't show my headphones in settings and i have no sound also.

Here is the output of alsa:

http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=13a5cc7cf7bf26689f340fb957f469cad475e9ef

If anybody can help, i would be very grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, i found my problem after detail searching. Thats something i've never heard befor and i have nowhere seen. Maybe it will help other too. I had to enable the sound card i bios. The "Audio" option i found under general settings, and then "audio". There i had to enable and then apply, and then i could enable the microphone and the headphone jack.